# LWJGL GLTranslation add to previos Translation

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

i've got a problem with coding here.
When i render 2 ore more blocks the location with the new block add with the old ones and so there's different distances between theese blocks. I used a FPCameraController and so I cannot add GL11.glloadIdentify() because my blocks disappears.

Rendering Class:

while(!Display.isCloseRequested) {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

```
            GL11.glCullFace(GL11.GL_BACK);
            GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
            GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);

            GL11.glPopMatrix(); //From 2D
            GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
            GL11.glLoadIdentity();
            GLU.gluPerspective(45f, (float) Display.getWidth() / Display.getHeight(), 0.1f, 1000);
            GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
            GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);



            //distance in mouse movement from the last getDX() call.
            dx = Mouse.getDX();
            //distance in mouse movement from the last getDY() call.
            dy = Mouse.getDY();

            //controll camera yaw from x movement fromt the mouse
            camera.yaw(dx * mouseSensitivity);
            //controll camera pitch from y movement fromt the mouse
            camera.pitch(dy * mouseSensitivity);

            //when passing in the distance to move
            //we times the movementSpeed with dt this is a time scale
            //so if its a slow frame u move more then a fast frame
            //so on a slow computer you move just as fast as on a fast computer
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W))//move forward
            {
                camera.walkForward(movementSpeed*dt);
            }
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S))//move backwards
            {
                camera.walkBackwards(movementSpeed*dt);
            }
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))//strafe left
            {
                camera.strafeLeft(movementSpeed*dt);
            }
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D))//strafe right
            {
                camera.strafeRight(movementSpeed*dt);
            }

             CubeRenderer.renderTexturedCube(TextureManager.cube_unknown.getTexture(), 0,0,0);
             CubeRenderer.renderTexturedCube(TextureManager.cube_unknown.getTexture(), 0,1,0);
             CubeRenderer.renderTexturedCube(TextureManager.cube_unknown.getTexture(), 0,2,0);
             CubeRenderer.renderTexturedCube(TextureManager.cube_unknown.getTexture(), 1,2,0);
             CubeRenderer.renderTexturedCube(TextureManager.cube_unknown.getTexture(), -1,2,0);
            GL11.glLoadIdentity();
            camera.lookThrough();




            Display.sync(60);
            Display.update();
    }
    Display.destroy();
```

Rendering class with these variables:
Texture tex;
float x,y,z;

GL11.glTranslatef(x,y,z);
         GL11.glRotatef(0,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
         GL11.glColor3f(0.5f,0.5f,1.0f);
         tex.bind();
         GL11.glPolygonMode(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_FILL);

```
     GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(-1, -1, 1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(1, -1, 1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1);
    GL11.glEnd();
    //left
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(-1, -1, -1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(-1, -1, 1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(-1, 1, -1);
    GL11.glEnd();
    //right
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(1, -1, -1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(1, 1, -1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(1, -1, 1);
    GL11.glEnd();
    //front
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(-1, -1, -1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(1, -1, -1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(1, -1, 1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(-1, -1, 1);
    GL11.glEnd();
    //back
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(1, 1, -1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(-1, 1, -1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    GL11.glEnd();
    //bottom
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(1, -1, -1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(-1, -1, -1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(-1, 1, -1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(1, 1, -1);
    GL11.glEnd();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GL11.glPushMatrix` to save the old matrix and `GL11.glPopMatrix` to restore it. In `renderTexturedCube` (or wherever you want):

```
GL11.glPushMatrix(); // saves the current matrix

GL11.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
GL11.glRotatef(0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // not sure why you have this; it does nothing

// rest of cube rendering code goes here

GL11.glPopMatrix(); // restore the matrix that was saved at the start of the method
```